# How to update table of content (TOC) for docx file by apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

How to update table of contents (TOC) and then convert docx file to pdf?
I want to create and update table of content in docx file and then convert it to pdf, so I want this TOC to be updated in pdf file.

This code update TOC after opening docx file by user and I don't need it.

```
docx.enforceUpdateFields();
```

I want TOC to be updated automatically by my program. Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6210694/1260472 for ideas

Comment: If I convert it to pdf, does TOC automatically update?@BudsNanKis

Comment: See your new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46759829/how-create-three-toc-with-diffrent-styles-in-docx-by-jav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comment in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24861645/how-to-create-or-update-table-of-contents-in-a-word-file#answer-24862870), I found out that there is no way to update TOC automatically. Ben said on that comment "*It then relies on a user to open the document in Word to generate the actual table of contents. Unfortunately, Word can't be made to update the TOC automatically and without user interaction*".